# How do I stop fwrite from breaking strings into the next line?

Tags: php

I am using `fwrite()` to write db queries into a file. It works fine except that the string gets broken and written in the next line. How can I make it print on a single line?

My code :

```
$fileNameArray = Array ( [0] => class.module.showinvoicelistme.php , [4] => home  );
$fileName ="class.module.showinvoicelist.php";
$fp = fopen("/home/Staging/fileUploadQuery",'w');
$text = "mv ".$fileNameArray[0]." ".$fileName."\r\n";
fwrite($fp,$text);`
```

Expected output :

`mv class.module.showinvoicelistme.php class.module.showinvoicelist.php`

What I get :

```
mv class.module.showinvoicelistme.php 

class.module.showinvoicelist.php
```

Comment: What exactly do you think `"\r\n"` does?

Comment: "\r\n" makes the fwrite skip a line after each line.

Comment: You should really show what `$fileNameArray` is / where it comes from, and also your sample output, and what you expect the output to look like.  It *certainly* doesn't make sense that you'd be trying to concatenate the array itself, and then one element from that array, to a string.

Comment: `"\r\n"` skips a line. My problem is that the string breaks up between  `"mv ".$fileNameArray."` and `".$fileNameArray[2]."\r\n"`

Comment: The first two lines are certainly not valid PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is probably not very clean.

You should `trim()` it, it will delete heading and trailing spaces and `\r` and `\n` ([See documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php)) :

```
$text = "mv ".trim($fileNameArray[0])." ".$fileName."\r\n";
```

Comment: Better use `trim` and/or `escapeshellarg`.